# Adding AI Analytics query to AI dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I created a couple of queries in Application Insights Analytics to get me the charts I want.

Example:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >= ago(31d)
| where name == "Search"
| project name, customDimensions, customMeasurements, customDimensions.["Query"]
| summarize  count() by tostring(customDimensions.["Query"])
| render piechart
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to add this query / chart to my Application Insights dashboard? I don't want to always have to go to the analytics tool to see this specific chart.

I've been googling but without result.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new capability is in the works and should be released in the upcoming weeks. Would definitely help to operationalize your queries. Stay tuned.

-Dan Hadari

---

Application Insights Team

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking forward to it. :)

Comment: This functionality i supported for long time. You can read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/query-language/get-started-analytics-portal#pin-to-dashboard
Note: the controls were updated and the UX is lightly different than what you will see in the documentation.